# AngularJS get JSON from Rails Controller with key (username)

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

Having problems getting my JSON request in Angular with specific format key (username). The following works just fine when I don't scope by `:username` in my route setup for api class. However, I want to be able to do this so I can run it by my `before_action` middleware function.

Alternative solutions are welcome, but I'm going for simple on this project, so allowing `get`,`post`, `patch`, `delete` calls like this would be great. I understand use `ngResource` might be a better solution. Below, I've included sample code I found on the internet, but I can't get it to work for my `:username` problem. I think that `ngResource` is better when you have a full crud model for an object, which I won't be using for most of my other models.

**Route.rb**

```
scope :api do
  scope ':username' do
    controller :ctrlname do
      get 'test' => :test, defaults: {format: :json}
    end
  end
end

scope :user do
  scope ':username' do
    controller :ctrlname do
      get 'test' => :test
    end
  end
end
```

**ctrlname_controller.rb**

```
before_action :authenticate_path!, except: [:home]

def home
end

def test
  @user = current_user # devise
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render action: @user }
    format.json { render json: {first: @user.name_first, last: @user.name_last, un: @user.username} }
  end
end

def authenticate_path!
  unless (params[:username] == current_user.username)
    raise Forbidden
  end
end
```

**main.js** (:username is my problem)

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("/api/:username/test").success(function(res) {
    $scope.data = res;
  });
}]);
```

**test.html.erb**

```
<h1>TEST</h1>
<div class="container" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <p>{{data.un}}</p>
</div>
```

**ngResource** code possibility (if I could adapt it to my problem, this does not work as is, but confirmed for working with a rails resource.)

```
app.factory('TestData', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  function TestData() {
    this.service = $resource('/api/:username/test', { username: '@user.username' });
  };
  TestData.prototype.all = function() {
    return this.service.query();
  };
  return new TestData;
}]);
```

Possible Solutions

Additional API call with loose restriction to get the ball rolling.

```
route.rb (changes)

scope :api do
  get 'user' => "ctrlname#home", defaults: {format: :json} # get username
  scope ':username' do
    controller :ctrlname do
      get 'test' => :test, defaults: {format: :json}
    end
  end
end

ctrlname_controller.rb (changes)

def home
  @user = current_user
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: {username: @user.username} }
  end
end

main.js (changes)

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("/api/user").success(function(user) {
  $scope.user = user;
  $http.get("/api/" + user.username + "/test").success(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
  });
});
```

}]);

Comment: Start with main.js, what will determine `username` value? There are no wildcards in `$http` for url so a simple string concatenation would be needed

Comment: @charlietfl Hmm, I suppose I could try getting to username of the currently logged in user using another api call, then concat with the string. And it worked. I suppose this is one solution, it requires an extra request, which is not ideal, but this is a simple app. Thank you very much, I'll share your solution with everyone. :)

Comment: Can also pass logged in username as variable in page load if it is already in session, and if not logged in get it during login process

Comment: @charlietfl You mean as a AngularJS model? I haven't tried that yet, I'll try that in a minute. That might work best because I already rendered the inital html with rails, because each route includes html action and json api call separately. I'd love to not request more than I have to.

Comment: Was thinking of simple global js variable object that can easily be added to script tag at server